# US 2011/0107630: waterfall flip-book cards

Tags: prior-art, us20110107630, cards-pictures-signs

Patent application [US 2011/0107630](http://www.google.com/patents/us20110107630) claims a type of flip book greeting cards. Here is claim 1:

> 1. A greeting card comprising:
>
> - a multi-panel greeting card body;
> - a flip book panel operatively engaged with the multi-panel greeting card body such that a first portion of the flip book panel is fixedly attached to at least One panel of the greeting card and a second portion of the flip book panel is able to move linearly relative to at least one panel of the greeting card body
> - the flip book panel having a plurality of sub-panels separated by fold lines,
> - the plurality of sub-panels arranged in a sequential stacked configuration, a first sub-panel containing an animation printed thereon and each consecutive sub-panel in the sequence containing a slight variation in the animation of the previous sub-panel in the sequence,
>
> wherein linear movement of the second portion of the flip book causes iteration of the plurality of sequentially stacked sub-panels creating the illusion of incremental movement of the animation printed thereon.

It is anticipated by a commonly known craft format known as waterfall flip cards, or waterfall flip-book cards.
Waterfall flip cards also use basically the same strip spine with multiple indented fold lines corresponding to the number of cards to be animated as in waterfall photo albums made of heat indented and die-cut vinyl.

So what is novel about the application? Also, how do you notify the patent office that there is prior art?

Comment: I'm not sure about your novelty question, but if you are interested in submitting prior art you should check out: [this meta discussion](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/105/i-want-to-make-a-difference-how-can-i-submit-prior-art-to-the-patent-office?cb=1), and [instructions for submitting prior art](http://www.groklaw.net/articlebasic.php?story=20120916162139282) as originally posted by Dennis Crouch in this question: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/743/prior-art-for-apple-heuristic-search-algorithm-pub-no-2012-0166477.

Comment: Looking at the drawings, it appears that one will pull the tab that will cause the folded "frames" to pop up and over sequentially, creating the animation effect. From the drawings alone, I cannot visualize how the frames will unfold (I feel the pulling will stretch the strip and flatten the folds). FYI "This application claims priority to U.S. Provisional Patent Application No. 61/260,508, filed on Nov. 12, 2009".

Comment: Can collecting this information, with the help of user privacy and the help of artificial intelligence, in a software help to collect all the accounts of each person to help recover the accounts created by the person himself? A kind of integration to retrieve the information of people who respect copyright and use active versions

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to the question - you may have not posted where you intended.